# python parsing from dynamic input line

Tags: python

i am trying a program for printing the words having 'good' using fuzzy ratio.Once i get the line it has to split and print next word:my program is not getting output

```
with open("qwer.txt",'r') as v1:
  for line in v1: 
    if 'good' in v1:
       print(v1)   
    if '=' in v1:    
       print v1.split('=')[1]

    if '==' in v1:
        print v1.split('==')[1]
```

qwer.txt:

```
Ram is very good=ideal student
Ram has nice character==Perfect student
```

output:

```
Ram is very good=ideal student
ideal
```

Its not executing once the statements provided,pls help me get the output!

Comment: What exactly is your question? That code is doing exactly what you ask it to - selecting the line with the highest `fuzz.ratio` (whatever that is) and printing what comes after the `'='`. Please provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that others can use to replicate the behaviour (i.e. including `fuzz.ratio`) and clearly explain how what you're getting differs from what you expected.

Comment: i edited the question,could u please help me get the output running?

Comment: Your new "code" won't run (`NameError` on `if 'good' in line`) and you **still haven't explained what the problem is**.

Comment: my prob is its not printing though it compiles without errors

Comment: So that's the output you *want*, not the output you're *getting*; make that clear in your question. Also, *read the article* I link above and provide an example that *actually works*. If others can't replicate your problem, how are they supposed to fix it? See also http://sscce.org.

Comment: If you want just the first word after the =,  'V1.split (''=')[1].split()[0]' would get "ideal"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are testing whether e.g. `'=='` is `in v1`, **not `line`**. Try:

```
with open("qwer.txt",'r') as v1:
  for line in v1: 
    if 'good' in line: # note 'line' from here on in
       print(line)   
    if '=' in line:    
       print line.split('=')[1]
    if '==' in line:
        print line.split('==')[1]
```

Which gives me:

```
Ram is very good=ideal student

ideal student


Perfect student
```

You should also bear in mind that your `'='` conditions aren't mutually exclusive; if `'=='` is in `line` then so is `'='`. It might be better like:

```
with open("qwer.txt",'r') as v1:
  for line in v1: 
    if 'good' in line: # note 'line' from here on
       print(line)   
    if '==' in line: # '==' first   
       print line.split('==')[1]
    elif '=' in line: # 'elif', not just 'if' 
        print line.split('=')[1]
```